# GridView produces strange white edge on padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gridview

I have the following layout containing only a GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On Android 2.3.3 (doesn't happen on 4.x) I noticed a white edge visible on the View according to the padding set on the GridView:

[image]

I thought the clipToPadding="false" would prevent that.

Oddly, I have the exact same layout containing a `<com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView>` from [this](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) library, which `extends GridView` and this doesn't have the white edge.

Anyone know the reason for this and a way to prevent it?

Comment: Does it show on scroll or it is stable at the time of load?

Comment: It's not visible at first because it's white and has a white background, and it end exactly where the first list item starts. But when you scroll it shows over the list items.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [android:fadingEdge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge) attribute to "none", or use the [setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled%28boolean%29) method to set the value to false.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: android:fadingEdge is depricated, use android:requiresFadingEdge